# No module named __future__

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I have error as `No module named __future__`.
I use tensorflow and it has Python2.7.
Once I run a program, I got error as shown below.

```
import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/coie/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from __future__ import absolute_import
ImportError: No module named __future__
```

How to install **future** into tensorflow's Python?

Comment: The `__future__` module is part of the core Python interpreter. If you're not able to load it, there's something badly wrong with your Python installation.

Answer (score 7):

Check that your Python modules are executable.

In your `/PATH/Python-2.7.x/Lib` should be all your modules, incl. **future**

If you don't have the above, re-install Python.

If you do, run `ls -l` which will show you the permissions associated with the modules in the first column. *.py should read `-rwxr-xr-x`. If it reads `-rw-r--r--` instead, the modules can't be imported or executed when they are called in your script. To fix this, change permissions with `sudo chmod +x *.py`.

Also, you need to check that python knows where to look for these modules. You can check this with `echo $PYTHONPATH` which should show you the path to you Lib directory. If not, set via `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/PATH/Python-2.7.13/Lib`. Also check out explanation and links in the answer to the following question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/250929/pythonpath-environment-variable

Comment: .py files do not need to be executable, they only need to be readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spyder in windows, go to search and type ''anaconda prompt'' , a prompt will appear, open it and type '' pip install future''. After installation is done, run your code again. Hope that solves the issue